# Correctly switching view controllers with MenuViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 view controllers right now: a `MenuViewController` and two top-level view controllers called `HomeViewController` and FoodCraftsViewController. Each of the top-level controllers are in their own navigation controller in the storyboard since they will eventually have child view controllers. MenuViewController is standalone in the storyboard. I'm programmatically adding `MenuViewController` as a sub view to these top-level view controllers in order to show the menu in a way where the navigation bar animates up out of view, and the main view animates down showing just the top part of it.

I've made `MenuViewController` a singleton class since all the top-level view controllers will use it. What I'm seeing in Xcode is that the memory slowly increases as you change views in the menu, which leads me to believe its creating a new navigation controller every time.

`MenuViewController` code for singleton instance:

```
class var sharedInstance: MenuViewController {
    struct Static {
        static var instance: MenuViewController?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController
    }
    return Static.instance!
}
```

MenuViewController code for navigating between top-level views (this is where I suspect the code is creating navigation controllers unnecessarily):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if self.parentViewController! != homeVC {
            if homeVC == nil {
                homeVC = storyboardMain.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
            }
            navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC!)
            navController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
            navController!.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
            self.presentViewController(navController!, animated: false, completion: nil)
        } else {
            homeVC?.hideMenu()
        }
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        if self.parentViewController! != foodCraftsVC {
            if foodCraftsVC == nil {
                foodCraftsVC = storyboardMain.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FoodCraftsViewController") as? FoodCraftsViewController
            }
            navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: foodCraftsVC!)
            navController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
            navController!.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
            self.presentViewController(navController!, animated: false, completion: nil)
        } else {
            foodCraftsVC?.hideMenu()
        }
    }
}
```

Code used in top-level view controllers (HomeViewController and FoodCraftsViewController) to add menu:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(false);

    for view in menuView.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    menuVC = MenuViewController.sharedInstance
    addChildViewController(menuVC!)
    menuView.addSubview(menuVC!.view)
    menuVC!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    menuVC!.homeVC = self
}
```

Any guidance is appreciated for optimizing this code. Thanks!